# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instabot'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I installed instabot in python by pip but I have this error in my pycharm:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instabot'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong python environment. Go to `File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter`. There will be a list of installed packages in python environment PyCharm is currently using. If `instabot` is not installed, click on the **+** sign and search for *instabot* and install it.

Press *apply* and *ok* and you can use module.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you set up multiple interpreters with the same version and then assign a python file to the interpreter.  You might be adding your packages in PyCharm > File > Settings to one interpreter, but not even realize you have configured another interpreter of the same Python version for a different environment under PyCharm > Python file dropdown > Edit Configuration.