# Python, 'no module named {package}' error

Tags: python, site-packages

I'm trying to use a package I installed using pip and it got installed in C:\Program Files\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages, but when I import it in my IDE I get an error saying `No module named instabot`. I have had this error before and I'm unsure of what is happening

Comment: You might be using a virtual env in your IDE

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are using a virtual environment in your IDE. If you using PyCharm, consider taking a look at this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593464/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-instabot)

Try `pip` or `pip3` installing it in the right environment depending on your python version.